# Grab a Column in MySQL in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have just learned MySQL in VB.NET, but I am having a complication..

When I grab a SELECT Query, I want to get - lets say the 'username' column in each row it receives. How would I do that?

```
 MySQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM online"
 MySQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Label1.Text = 'usernamehere'
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub CreateMySqlDataReader(mySelectQuery As String, myConnection As MySqlConnection)
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Try
    While myReader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0))
    End While
Finally
    myReader.Close
    myConnection.Close
    End Try
End Sub
```

Found on: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executereader

Also as a bonus. If you are going to throw in some parameters in that query I would suggest you look into prepared statements.

Comment: I've been looking into this since you posted it, and nothing is being written. myReader.Read() is returning False, thus not giving me any rows.